# reset forms inside an iframe from same domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a 3rd party chat service that makes you use iframe to host your own chat. They allow you to place html and javascript so I was wondering how i can add a button to clear the forms in the "formsframe" iframe

**main frame**

```
<iframe src="http://www.chat.com/529552/?main" name="mainframe" id="mainframe"></iframe>
```

**forms frame**

```
<iframe src="http://www.chat.com/529552/?forms" name="formframe" id="formframe"></iframe>
```

**forms names**:
name, email, message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formframe').ready(function() {
         $('#formframe').content().find('form').append('<input type="reset" value="Reset" />');
      });
   });
```